# Add validation in formitem in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, antd

In my reactjs code I want to add validation for password and email. How?

```
            <Col span={12}>
                <FormItem>
                    {getFieldDecorator('Password', {
                        initialValue: "",
                        rules: [{
                            required: true, message: 'Please Input your Password!',
                        }],
                    })(
                        <Input placeholder="Password" />
                    )}
                </FormItem>
            </Col>

            <Col span={12}>
                <FormItem>
                    {getFieldDecorator('Email', {
                        initialValue: "",
                        rules: [{
                            required: true, message: 'Please Input your Email!',
                        }],
                    })(
                        <Input placeholder="Email" />
                    )}
                </FormItem>
            </Col>
```

Also I want to hide password by bullets or anything else

Comment: Welcome to SO @Levina! In order to help you better, we'll need more detail about the technologies you're using. It looks like you're using Ant Design is that right? If so, make sure to include antd in your tag of this post.

Comment: yes, it is.....

Comment: Your question needs some more details, just like I guess, you are using `Ant` library for your project, this kind of question never got an answer. because you didn't try to solve your problem. even you didn't search to find some trend validation examples or functions. I upvoted your question but please try and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this codepen with simple email and password validation:
https://codepen.io/lukejsimonetti/pen/XxgbgP?editors=0010

You're close. Looks like you're missing the `type` in the rules. Something like this:

```
            <FormItem
                {...formItemLayout}
                label="E-mail"
            >
                {getFieldDecorator('email', {
                    rules: [{
                        // declare the type and message here
                        type: 'email', message: 'The input is not valid E-mail!',
                    }, {
                        required: true, message: 'Please input your E-mail!',
                    }],
                })(
                    <Input />
                )}
            </FormItem>
            <FormItem
                {...formItemLayout}
                label="Password"
            >
                {getFieldDecorator('password', {
                    rules: [{
                        required: true, message: 'Please input your password!',
                    }, {

                        // run some custom validator function here on your class
                        validator: this.compareToConfirmPassword,
                    }],
                })(
                    <Input type="password" />
                )}
            </FormItem>
```

Taken from the Ant Design docs here: 
https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-register